# How to get array values in string variable from multidimensional array Using Php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional array and want to get all values with comma without loop in a string variable.

Is it possible ?

Array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 61
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 62
        )
)
```

I want to get like this : `61,62` .

How to do this ?

Comment: This is array of object. Post the actual data not the `print_r`

Comment: create a loop and get `$v->id`. just show what you tried to get?

Comment: i want to get without loop

Answer (score 0):

Just do a loop over array and make new array to get values, Then convert new array to comma separated string.

```
foreach($arr as $v){
 $newarr[] = $v->id;
}
// Convert new array to comma separated string
$str = implode(',', $newarr);
```

or

use `array_map()`

```
function getid($v) {
    return $v->id;
}
$str = implode(array_map("getid", $arr), ',');
echo $str;
```

Comment: can i get it without loop because i have large amount of data and this array is already in an array so already looping and again if i loop it this will take more time.